# What kind of middleware nova in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have routes that should be available only when I logged nova admin. How can I find out which middleware a nova is using?
Or is there some other way to do this?

```
Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('main')
        ->group(function () {
            Route::get('/', [TestController::class, 'index']);
        });
});
```

I used middleware `(['auth'])`, but when I go to the admin panel, the paths are still not available to me.
if I use middleware `(['web'])` then my paths are always available

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: @РомаЛытарь not available? 404? 403? And tell us the full path you are going to

Comment: @WahyuKristianto the question is that when I am not logged into the admin panel in a NOVA , then my paths are available "http/127.0.0.1/admin/main/" and should not be available when I am not logged in in a NOVA.

Comment: @РомаЛытарь can you show me what an error (not available) you have? It it 404? 403? or something?

Comment: 401 code error, not authorized